# where clause from where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i need to do this :

There is a table called table1  it has a employee id column,status column which has values 1 and 0 only  and a department column with values 100,101,102.

i want to list all employeeid with the status = 0 and (department=100 whose status=1)

Please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Where Status = 0 or (Department = 100 And Status = 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write your condition in SQL almost like you wrote it in english *(except you'll use a `or` instead of a `and`)* :

```
select *
from table1
where status = 0
    or (status = 1 and department = 100)
```

This will return all employees :

- that have a 0 status
- or have a 1 status and have departement 100