# Where clause in where - version 2 :-)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i need to do this :

There is a table called table1 it has a employee id column,status column which has values 1 and 0 only and a department column with values 100,101,102.

i want to list all employeeid with the status = 0

from the above list i want to filter the employees which having (department=100 and whose status=1)

Extended question:

i want to include only whose department is 100 and status =1 from the list of status=0 employees

Please help me

Comment: I think you should show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: The first list filters all status = 0, filtering again to status = 1 would yield 0 results in all cases, clarify a bit?

Comment: lf list is with status = 0 then a filter with status =1 will have no effect.

Also what have you tried and what were the problems with the results

Comment: Do you mean, you want all employees whose status = 0, and then take their departments, and then find the employees in those departments whose status = 1?

Comment: Actually, how is this different to your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419043/where-clause-from-where-clause

Comment: i want to exclude whose department is 100 and status =1 from the list of status=0 employees

Comment: @SmartestVEGA: if you want to exclude employees whose status is 1, you've already done that by listing all employees whose status = 0.  Once more thing I'm unclear on, do you need to include employees whose status is 0 and department is 100?  In other words, do you mean that you want to exclude anyone whose status is 1 and at the same time whose department is 100, or just anyone whose status is 1 or anyone else whose department is 100?

Comment: sorry not exclude its include ..appologises ..i have edited the question

Comment: @SmartestVEGA if you wish to INCLUDE my answer below should work for you

Comment: Can an employee appear more than once in the table with two different statuses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you've phrased it incorrectly and want OR instead of AND, try this..

```
select * 
  from table1
 where (status=0) or (status=1 and department=100)
```

**Edit**

If you only want the employeeid then do this

```
 select employeeid
   from table1
  where (status=0) or (status=1 and department=100)
```

**Edit No.2**

Covering all bases, if you want to find all employees who don't have a status of 0, or a status of 1 and department of 100 then try this!!

```
 select employeeid
   from table1
  where not (status=0) and not (status=1 and department=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you've left out an important part of the problem statement: each employeeid can be in table1 more than one time.  I'm assuming that you want employees with one record indicating status 0 and a second record indicating department 100 / status 1.

If so, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 AS E0
   INNER JOIN Table1 AS D100 
   ON E0.EmployeeID = D100.EmployeeID
   WHERE E0.Status = 0 AND D100.Department = 100 AND D100.Status = 1
```

If I understand your question correctly, this should approach what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt make sense...you want to filter all employees whose status is 0.
And once you have filtered these records you want to refilter that original filter to include all employees which have department 100 (which is still ok), but then you want the status to be 1.  How can that be given that you stated in your original request you only wanted employees with 0 status???

Think about it and take it from a person trying to answer your question.
You have 10 records, half of them have employees with a 0 status and the other half have a 1 status.

```
Jon1  1
Jon2  1
Jon3  1
Jon4  1
Jon5  1

JOn6  0
Jon7  0
Jon8  0
Jon9  0
Jon10 0
```

So you want all employees with 0:

```
JOn6  0
Jon7  0
Jon8  0
Jon9  0
Jon10 0
```

Simple enough : `SELECT blah FROM Employees WHERE Status=0`

Now you want another query which has their department number of 100 but have a status of 1.  Well how can you find one that has a status of 1 when you filtered for a status of 0????

You probably want an OR condition:

```
SELECT blah FROM myTable WHERE EmpStatus=0 OR (EmpStatus=1 AND Dept=100)
```

Which clearly is a different question...

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple rows with the same EmployeeID (just guessing here), then you may want to try the following query.

```
Select EmployeeId
From   Table1
Group By EmployeeId
Having Count(Case When Status = 0 Then 1 End) > 0
       And Count(Case When Status = 1 And Department = 100 Then 1 End) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this, if I'm understanding you correctly.

```
SELECT *
  FROM emp_dept e1
 WHERE status = 0
   AND EXISTS( SELECT *
                 FROM emp_dept e2
                WHERE e2.id     = e1.id
                  AND e2.status = 1
                  AND e2.dept   = 100 )
```